# how to correctly set legend and colors with arviz.plot_bpv

Tags: python, matplotlib, pymc, arviz

I'm trying to manually specify colors for lines in arviz.plot_bpv to evaluate the impact of a model parameter. However, I'm facing challenges in correctly displaying the legend.

How should I set the legend in order to each line be different? For example, in the image below, sigma 1 and sigma 3 has the same black dashed line. Also the legend in the ax[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kblq.png) is not ok.

```
import matplotlib
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
RANDOM_SEED = 58
rng = np.random.default_rng(RANDOM_SEED)

data = pd.read_csv(pm.get_data("babies.csv"))
X = data.Month.values
Y = data.Length.values
sigma_test = [1,10,100,1000]

with pm.Model() as model:
    Y = pm.ConstantData('Y',Y)
    X = pm.MutableData('X',X)
    sigma = pm.MutableData('sigma_test',sigma_test[0])
    
    intercept = pm.LogNormal('Intercept', mu=3., sigma=1.)
    slope = pm.Normal('Slope', mu=0.5, sigma=0.1)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sigma=sigma)
    mu = pm.Deterministic('mu',slope * X + intercept)
    
    likelihood = pm.Normal('y_est', mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed = Y,shape=X.shape[0])
    
# Generate one trace for each sigma
trace = []
post_pred = []
for sigma_vals in sigma_test:
    with model:
        # Switch out the sigma
        pm.set_data({"sigma_test": sigma_vals})
        trace_i = pm.sample(random_seed=rng)
        trace.append(trace_i)
        post_pred.append(pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_i,extend_inferencedata=True,random_seed=rng))
        
# Plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))
legend_labels = []  # To store legend labels
colors = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4','C5','C6']
for i in range(len(sigma_test)):
    post_pred_i = post_pred[i]
    az.plot_bpv(post_pred_i, kind="p_value",color=colors[i], ax=ax[0])
    az.plot_bpv(post_pred_i, kind="u_value",color=colors[i], ax=ax[1])
    
    # Append a label to the legend_labels list
    legend_labels.append(f"Sigma {i}")

# Make sure to adjust the labels or titles for your subplots as needed
ax[0].set_title("P-Values")
ax[1].set_title("U-Values")

# Add a legend to the subplots
ax[0].legend(legend_labels)
ax[1].legend(legend_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]